# Why 'apt-get install' acquires /var/cache/apt/archives/lock during download

Tags: apt, dpkg

The `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get install <packagename>` commands acquire `/var/cache/apt/archives/lock` while both downloading and installing.

I think it should be possible to download packages without acquiring the lock. We should need to acquire the lock only when upgrading/installing the downloaded packages. What do you think? Why can't we download more than one package at the same time? Or why can't we download packages while installing another one?

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: sorry, my fault. `apt-get download package-name` only download the `package-name` to the current directory. then it is not an answer to your question.

`apt-get download` is also not download the package dependencies.

an alternative to download the packages and dependencies, but not install would: `sudo apt-get -d install package-name`

but it also does not solve the lock problem.

I think it's not possible to run two instances of apt-get in simuntanea way

if your goal is to download the packages faster way, perhaps an option is to use apt-fast (https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast) instead of apt-get (in my case, I use apt-fast because I have a very unstable internet connection)

previous response:

an option is to use `apt-get download package-name` to only download  the package and then run `sudo apt-get install package-name` to install downloaded package.

`apt-get download` not create a lock.

you can run simultaneously `apt-get download` and `sudo apt-get install`

Comment: one issue with that is your install can duplicate downloading packages or try to install half downloaded packages

Comment: wouldn't `apt-get install` redownload the package?

Comment: @adonis if the package is in the cache (`/var/cache/apt/archives/`) and is the latest version available in the repository, no, it will not download again.

Comment: `apt-get download` downloads to the current folder though.

Answer (score 3):

The lock is used to ensure that only one process can change the apt database at time. If another process was installing a package and one was installing one they could end up getting very confused and corrupt the database. for more on this concept google 'database transactions' or 'atomicity'.

You can avoid the locks by downloading the packages yourself using the links from /etc/apt/sources.list and browsing them in your web browser. You can then install the debs you have downloaded with gdebi or dpkg. However if you do this you will have to resolve the dependencies yourself which isn't allways easy and is IMHO way more annoying than the locks.

If the locks are annoying then consider batching your installs to include multiple packages e.g. apt-get install package1 package2 package3 and go make some tea.